# Git-Flow - "separate component" - How?

Tags: git, git-flow

We use git-flow. Sometimes our developers create independent software components.

These components are specifically developed for the project. But can be developed separately, outside the development environment. This reduces the overhead of having to compile the entire codebase everytime a developer wants to test the component.

Once the "component" is ready, the class (or whatever) will then be added to the feature branch.

How would one go about this following Git-flow conventions? Do we just create a new separate repo?

Comment: Why do you want to add it to the feature branch if it is a separate tool? I would leave it in a separate repository, so the whole project doesn't get unnecessarily large.